# encrypted and decrypted password in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, encryption

i want to store encrypted password in my mysql database.

i have insert the password like ari means have to save the password like B-dd2c1cd0250859d32754fdd85ffc0531.

But i have to insert the data(**ari**) means the ari is displayed on my database.how can i encrupt the password and save the password like above format.

For eg:
ari is save in database like these format B-dd2c1cd0250859d32754fdd85ffc0531.how can i do.please help me.

i have wrote the code:

```
public class Insert {

   public String insertData(String userName,String userPassword){

   try{

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://server:3306/android","XXXX","XXX");
   PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO xcart_customers(login,password) VALUES ('"+userName+"','"+userPassword+"');");
       int result = statement.executeUpdate();
       }

          catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
          }

          return "Insertion successfull!!";
        }}
```

This is my Demo.java class:

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Insert obj = new Insert();
    System.out.println(obj.insertData("krishna", "ari"));
   }
  }
```

Comment: What you do not know ? How to save data ? How to encrypt data ? How to decrypt data. Please create a question not statement.

Comment: @Vash how is store encrypted password in database in java using jdbc

Comment: You need to do that yourself, nothing in JDBC is going to encrypt it for you.

Comment: JDBC is a database access API. It won't encrypt anything. That's not its job. Your database might have encryption SQL functions. Java has cryptographic APIs. But JDBC is not the one that will do the job. Note that passwords should not be encrypted. They should be salted, then hashed.

Comment: @user1897014 are showing DB sensitive information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the sql query `INSERT INTO xcart_customers(login,password)` I guess you are trying to encrypt passwords for X-CART.

X-CART uses Blowfish key-based encryption. You can find your key from config.php -file.

Here's a already answered question about encrypting blowfish with a key in java which might help figuring out how encrypt it

[Encryption with BlowFish in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244950/encryption-with-blowfish-in-java)

Comment: Hi.,this is my updated code like:http://pastie.org/5555969                            here i got the following error :Cannot find any provider supporting password                                                                                                         whats wrong in my code.please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at password hashing and salting. Have a look at [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-md5-hashing-salting-password/) post.

**EDIT:**

Remember Hashing is One way! so you can't expect to convert the Hashed value back to the clear text (in this case ari). What you can do is when login works you can check user entered value is equal or not to the database value.

Comment: Do *not* use MD5, though. It's been broken forever.

Comment: True. Better to avoid SHA as well. AES might be more secure.

Comment: @shazin: AES is not a hashing algorithm. It's a secret-key encryption algorithm. It can't replace MD5 or SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which scheme was used to encrypt the existing data, there's no way to tell how you can achieve compatibility. If you can start all over again, [bcrypt is the way to go](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).