# How to use strong encryption for password field using grails with postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, grails, password-encryption

I had to migrate a legacy database with clear text password to a PostgresSQL database. I've looked up what's the best way to encrypt password in a database and found the pgcrypto extension with slow algorithm. (see [pgcrypto documentation for 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/pgcrypto.html))

The migration is done for data and everything is working well.
Now I have to write a CRUD application to handle this data.
I'm wondering what's the best way to use this strong encryption with grails ?

In my model, I've used the afterInsert event to handle this :

```
def afterInsert() { 
    Compte.executeUpdate("update Compte set hashpass=crypt(hashpass, gen_salt('bf', 8)) where id = (:compteId)", [compteId: this.id])
}
```

I guess that I should also check if the hashpass field is modified whenever the model is saved. But before that, is there another (best) way to achieve my goal ?

**Edit** : I cannot use the [Spring Security bcrypt plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-bcrypt) here. The CRUD application that I'm writing use SSO CAS so I don't need such a plugin. The CRUD application manages accounts for another application that I don't own. I just need to create a new account, modify or delete an existing one. This is very simple. The tricky part is to hack grails so that it takes into account the password field and use a specific sql to store it to a postgreSQL database.

**Edit 2** :

I've come up with the following code but it doesn't work

```
def beforeInsert() {
    hashpass = encodePassword(hashpass);
}

def encodePassword(cleartextpwd) {
    // create a key generator based upon the Blowfish cipher
    KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");

    // create a key
    SecretKey secretkey = keygenerator.generateKey();

    // create a cipher based upon Blowfish
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

    // initialise cipher to with secret key
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkey);

    // get the text to encrypt
    String inputText = cleartextpwd;

    // encrypt message
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(inputText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
}
```

I get a hash that is not a blowfish hash (beginning with $2a$08$ )

**Edit 3** :

I've finally came up with a cleaner grails solution after reading this wiki page : grails.org/Simple+Dynamic+Password+Codec (not enough reputation to put more than 2 links so add http:// before) and the bug report jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3620

Following advice from @lukelazarovic, I've also used the algorithm from the spring security plugin.

Here is my password encoder to put into grails/utils :

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.encoding.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

class BlowfishCodec {

static encode(target) {
            // TODO need to put the logcount = 8 in configuration file
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8).encodePassword(
        target, null)
}
}
```

I've updated my Compte model to call my password encoder before saving / updating the data :

```
def beforeInsert() {
    hashpass = hashpass.encodeAsBlowfish();
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if(isDirty('hashpass')) {
            hashpass = hashpass.encodeAsBlowfish();
    }
}
```

Comment: look like you are putting raw password into database, and only then applying a hash. so there is a moment when hacker can have access to original password, right? is it a possible security hole?

Comment: You're right and that's why I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Better solution is to use already existing safe solution in form of plugin, like spring-security. Secure password saving (hash algorithm used is configurable), authentization, authorization etc. is all already solved there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The tricky part is to hack grails so that it takes into account the
>   password field and use a specific sql to store it to a postgreSQL
>   database.

Is there any particular reason to do the hashing in database?

IMHO it's better to hash the password in Grails, therefore have a code that is not database-specific and easier to read.

For hashing passwords using Blowfish algorithm using Java or Groovy see [Encryption with BlowFish in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244950/encryption-with-blowfish-in-java)

The resulting hash begins with algorithm specification, iteration count and salt, separated with dollar sign - '$'. So the hash may look like `"$2a$08$saltCharacters"` where 2a is a algorithm, 08 is iteration count, then follows salt and after salt is the hash itself.

For broader explanation see http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australian-technology/securing-passwords-with-blowfish. Don't mind that it concerns to Blowfish in PHP, the principles applies for Java or Groovy as well.

Comment: I'm using the blowfish algorithm. I'm not sure if Grails can generate the same hash as the postgreSQL database. But it worth a try.

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario when you get different results using same standardized hashing algorithm on same input on two different platforms other than that on one of these platforms the implementation of this algorithm contains a MAJOR bug.

Comment: Added explanation to the answer